# Trying to figure out integral example form the book

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve one example from the book I have, but when I look at the solution it puzzles me.

Maybe you can tell me why is it so!

This is the example:
$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} x^n\sin(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$$
Calculating this is done by partial integration, where:
$$
u = x^n\\
\mathrm{d}u = nx^{n-1} \ \mathrm{d}x\\
\mathrm{d}v = \sin(x)\\
v = -\cos(x)\\
$$
Now I am confused about the next step in the book. The example goes like this:
$$
=[-nx^{n-1}\cos(x)]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+n\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} x^{n-1}\cos(x)\ \mathrm{d}x
$$
Why is here $v$ and $\mathrm{d}u$ two times used in solution, when the formula goes like:
[image: partial integration]

Comment: I take it your issue is with the first part?  It looks like an error.  They used $du$ instead of $u$.

Comment: Yes that is my issue, is that possible to do or is ot justa mistake

Comment: It is indeed an error.  Replace that first $nx^{n-1}$ with $x^n$ and it should be correct.

Comment: You need to integrate by parts twice. So, you will have a recurrence relation for your result.